# Where to store a binary file to be used for unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, resources, mocking, directory-structure

Where should I store a resource (binary file in my case) that I need to use for unit testing?

Specifically, my directory structure is a standard:

```
src -> main -> java -> com.company.project -> classes...
    -> test -> java -> com.company.project -> classes...
```

I want to mock a file being read from the file system and replace it with a file from within my project.

Comment: have you tried JUNIT? try [JUnit TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src\test\resources` is a good place for resources you need for unit-testing, if you are using mavens standard directory layout.

Read more about the different directories here:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I consider needing a binary resource for unit testing as a code smell. It suggests that the API of your code is not expressive enough:  all it can take as input is a blob of bytes. What is in this resource? Is it really just a stream of bytes,or does it have some structure?

If your code parses this binary input, consider instead also writing code for writing this binary format as output, then test that writing-followed-by-reading is symmetric. If you do not want your code to *provide* functionality for writing the binary format, make those methods package-private, rather than `public`, or put them in a class that you use only for testing.

If your code does not parse this binary input, but instead calls some other code to parse the binary and uses the result of that parsing, alter the API of your code so its input is that parsed data.

Comment: Actually, what you wrote about testing writing-followed-by-reading is exactly what I do in part of the tests. However, I have testing for legacy formats that are no longer supported for writing but I am supposed to have backward compatibility for them, hence I need to save the files as resource. Unless you have a better idea?

Comment: That would have been a good idea if they were not taken out a while ago by someone else without asking me... :/

Comment: Well, get them back from the old version in your version control system. You *do* use a version control system, don't you?

Comment: Of course we use VCS, but that would be going beyond the scope of my current task (finding it, re-integrating it with the current code, testing it, etc.), and I do have deadlines... Unfortunately I don't live in a utopic environment.